# MySQL Workbench SSH Connection error

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, workbench

When I try to connect to my MySQL server using MySQL Workbench - I get the following error:

```
'Error Connecting to Server (root@ipaddress)

Could not establish SSH connection: Error reading SSH protocol banner.'
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I would love a pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue.

The issue was that I was trying to connect to the SSH port instead of the MySQL port. When using this over SSH connections - you want to configure the SSH connection, and make sure you connect to the 'MySQL' port, since this is a pseudo-VPN connection.